# javac compilation - code in multiple folders

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I have been sitting on it for a while and can't figure it out, although I think it's quite easy...

I have to compile the following program using javac (the program has one class and one testing class):

- a class is in folder `./src/cplx/`
- a testing class is in folder `./test/cplx/`
- junit lib is in `./lib`

and:

- classes should be built to `./build/slasses`
- testing classes should be build to `./build/test`

Please help me with writing a proper `javac` command to compile the code.

---

I used the suggested command end het the following error, it looks like test class doesn't see the class i have built?

```
amaltea:testowanie/zad1% javac -d ./build/classes ./src/cplx/*.java
amaltea:testowanie/zad1% javac -classpath ./lib/junit-4.8.2.jar -d ./build/test ./test/cplx/*.java
./test/cplx/ComplexTest.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Complex
location: class cplx.ComplexTest
                Complex a = new Complex(1.1, 2.2);
                ^
./test/cplx/ComplexTest.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Complex
location: class cplx.ComplexTest
                Complex a = new Complex(1.1, 2.2);
                                ^
2 errors
amaltea:testowanie/zad1%
```

Comment: Ant is really a better way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify only one root destination directory with javac. If you want the root itself to be different you need to compile them separately.

```bsh
javac -d ./build/classes ./src/cplx/*.java
javac -classpath ./lib/junit.jar -d ./build/test ./test/cplx/*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's nice to start off using javac to grasp what is going on at a lower level and understand the language and tools before you begin using more advanced stuff, I think some Ant build script or an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans would serve you better. At least if you just want a result rather than understanding all the details. You can always learn more about those later. Anyway, the official documentation should tell you what you need to know: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify one more thing in *-classpath* option..
it should be:

```
javac -classpath ./build/classes/:lib/junit-4.8.2.jar -d ./test/classes test/cplx/*.java
```

That's information where your Complex.class file is.